# QVariant to QObject*

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm trying to attach a pointer to an `QListWidgetItem`, to be used in the slot `itemActivated`.

The pointer I'm trying to attach is a `QObject*` descendant, so, my code is something like this:

```
Image * im = new Image();  
// here I add data to my Image object
// now I create my item
QListWidgetItem * lst1 = new QListWidgetItem(*icon, serie->getSeriesInstanceUID(),  m_iconView);
// then I set my instance to a QVariant
QVariant v(QMetaType::QObjectStar, &im)
// now I "attach" the variant to the item.
lst1->setData(Qt::UserRole, v);
//After this, I connect the SIGNAL and SLOT
...
```

Now my problem, the `itemActivated` slot. Here I need to extract my `Image*` from the variant, and I don't know how to.

I tried this, but I get the error:

> ‘qt_metatype_id’ is not a member of ‘QMetaTypeId’

```
void MainWindow::itemActivated( QListWidgetItem * item )
{
    Image * im = item->data(Qt::UserRole).value<Image *>();
    qDebug( im->getImage().toAscii() );
}
```

Any hint?

```
Image * im = item->data(Qt::UserRole).value<Image *>();
```

Comment: From the `QVariant(int typeId, const void *copy)` ctor documentation: "Usually, you never have to use this constructor, use [QVariant::fromValue()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue) instead to construct variants from the pointer types represented by QMetaType::VoidStar, and QMetaType::QObjectStar."

Comment: Also note that the type of `&im` is `Image**`, not `Image*`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is this

```
// From QVariant to QObject *
QObject * obj = qvariant_cast<QObject *>(item->data(Qt::UserRole));
// from QObject* to myClass*
myClass * lmyClass = qobject_cast<myClass *>(obj);
```

Comment: Nope, you wrote what to do, but I needed HOW TO DO IT.

Comment: Why don't you use the `qvariant_cast` to directly cast to `myClass*`? Like this: `myClass * lmyClass = qvariant_cast<myClass *>(item-data(Qt::UserRole));`?

Comment: Nevermind: Looking at the implementation of `qvariant_cast` told me why: the type parameter for qvariant_cast must (should?) be known to the meta-object system.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an unusual use of `QVariant`.  I'm not even sure if `QVariant` would support holding a `QObject` or `QObject*` that way.  Instead, I would try deriving from `QListWidgetItem` in order to add custom data, something like this:

```
class ImageListItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
  // (Not a Q_OBJECT)
public:
  ImageListItem(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text,
                Image * image,
                QListWidget * parent = 0, int type = Type);
  virtual ~ImageListItem();
  virtual QListWidgetItem* clone(); // virtual copy constructor
  Image * getImage() const;

private:
  Image * _image;
};

void MainWindow::itemActivated( QListWidgetItem * item )
{
     ImageListItem *image_item = dynamic_cast<ImageListItem*>(item);
     if ( !image_item )
     {
          qDebug("Not an image item");
     }
     else
     {
         Image * im = image_item->getImage();
         qDebug( im->getImage().toAscii() );
     }
}
```

Plus, the destructor of this new class gives you somewhere logical to make sure your `Image` gets cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks aschepler for this nice and clean solution.

Comment: Sorry aschepler, this won't work. The SIGNALS are not emitted, how can I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've inserted your Image class as QObject *, so get it out as QObject * also. Then perform qobject_cast and everything should be fine