# QVariant call a function of a stored object, but crash when get value<QObject*>()

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My QML get object C++ via Q_PROPERTY as QVariant type.

I get crash when trying get QVariant::value()
My guess maybe the contained object memory have been deleted.

```
*** Aborted at 1696848320 (unix time) try "date -d @1696848320" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0xf1) received by PID 15139 (TID 0x7f78fe9df200) from PID 241; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f78d1816390 (unknown)
    @     0x7f78fa283823 QV4::QObjectWrapper::wrap()
    @     0x7f78fa27b8b5 QV4::ExecutionEngine::fromVariant()
    @     0x7f78fa32bd06 loadProperty()
    @     0x7f78fa32ee47 QV4::QObjectWrapper::getProperty()
    @     0x7f78fa4b4a4a QV4::QQmlTypeWrapper::lookupSingletonProperty()
    @     0x7f78fa4b64ec QV4::QQmlTypeWrapper::virtualResolveLookupGetter()
    @     0x7f78fa28ecd5 QV4::Lookup::resolveGetter()
    @     0x7f78fa28f44a QV4::Lookup::getterGeneric()
    @     0x7f78fa34cdfc QV4::Moth::VME::interpret()
    @     0x7f78fa35587d QV4::Moth::VME::exec()
    @     0x7f78fa2c0ba8 QV4::Function::call()
    @     0x7f78fa49d34c QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate()
    @     0x7f78fa4435c8 QQmlBoundSignalExpression::evaluate()
    @     0x7f78fa4440c3 QQmlBoundSignal_callback()
    @     0x7f78fa479afc QQmlNotifier::emitNotify()
    @     0x7f78fa4207c5 QQmlData::signalEmitted()
    @     0x7f78f9820fcd doActivate<>()
    @     0x7f78f981a30b QMetaObject::activate()
    @     0x7f78fa4149cb QQmlVMEMetaObject::activate()
    @     0x7f78fa41954a QQmlVMEMetaObject::metaCall()
    @     0x7f78f97f1bf9 QMetaObject::metacall()
    @     0x7f78fa47a10e QQmlObjectOrGadget::metacall()
    @     0x7f78fa32d175 CallMethod()
    @     0x7f78fa32d37b CallPrecise()
    @     0x7f78fa32e019 QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal()
    @     0x7f78fa32e055 QV4::QObjectMethod::virtualCall()
    @     0x7f78fa34deae QV4::Moth::VME::interpret()
    @     0x7f78fa35587d QV4::Moth::VME::exec()
    @     0x7f78fa2c0ba8 QV4::Function::call()
    @     0x7f78fa49d34c QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate()
    @     0x7f78fa4435c8 QQmlBoundSignalExpression::evaluate()
10:45:20: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

=> My question: How to check if the contained object is invalid or bad address or catch error when QVariant::value with SegFault?

Add example:

In main.cpp

```
{
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<HeaderModel>("com.my.example", 1, 0, "HeaderModel", &HeaderModel::qmlInstance);
    ...
}
```

HeaderModel.hpp

```
{

    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant baseModel READ getBaseModel WRITE setBaseModel NOTIFY baseModelChanged)
    ...

public:
 
    QVariant getBaseModel() const;
    void setBaseModel(const QVariant& baseModel);
    
private:
    QVariant m_baseModel;   
}
```

and HeaderModel.cpp

```
QVariant getBaseModel::baseModel() const
{
    //For debug: print QVariant's property
    if (m_baseModel.canConvert<QObject*>())
    {
        QObject *sp = m_baseModel.value<QObject*>();
        qDebug() << " objectName: " << sp->objectName().toStdString();
    }

    return m_baseModel;
}
void HeaderModel::setBaseModel(const QVariant& baseModel)
{
    m_baseModel = baseModel;
    emit baseModelChanged()
}
```

QML file:

```
Guest.qml
=================
MouseArea{
    id: mouseArea
    onClicked: HeaderModel.baseModel = factorModel #which is C++ object already make available in QML
}

Header.qml
=================
...
id: header
signal tapHandler()

onTapHandler:
{
    if(HeaderModel.baseModel !== null){
        HeaderModel.baseModel.doSomething()
    }
}

MouseArea{
    id: mouseArea
    onClicked: header.tapHandler()
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried using `qvariant_cast`? e.g. `QObject *sp = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(baseViewModel);` For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918893/881441

Comment: Hi  Stephen Quan
I tried  `qvariant_cast` but same error.I think it still needs to access the memory of the object containing it, but that memory is no longer valid.
I don't know any way to check that, or catch an error

Comment: You should be very careful about passing raw pointers to QML managed objects into C++ code. Maybe your QML code has already deleted the object you're trying to look at. Without a [mre], all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Hi @JarMan,
I also speculated this. I check the properties of the QVariant they are still valid, e.x: `type(), data(), canConvert<QObject*>()`, ..
Only show SIGSEGV error when I try `cast` by `value()`, `qvariant_cast()`.
But I can't catch error here.

Comment: Hi @JarMan
Added example.

Comment: The problem probably originated to some choices that needed to be made when you converted the QObject* to QVariant for QML consumption, since, the QObjectOwnership::JavaScriptOwnership may need to be set so that it is managed by the QML/JS garbage collector. That would ensure that your object will continue to exist for when that object comes back from QML/JS to C++. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494227/881441

Comment: Thank for your info,
But in this case, Any suggestion to check object is exist/valid or catch an error here ?